# Ansible change all dict key values only by filters

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an ansible dict like

```
ports:
  webui: 7200
  webadmin: 7209
  core_api: 7201
  stock_api: 7204
  import_export: 7207
```

And i want to transform all keys in it, like

```
ports:
  staging-webui: 7200
  staging-webadmin: 7209
  staging-core_api: 7201
  staging-stock_api: 7204
  staging-import_export: 7207
```

I do that in 'vars' section, so i can't use 'set_fact' with 'with_items' to iterate over dict. Is it possible to it only by filters?

I found working answer,

```
env: staging # comes from outside

regex_env: "\"key\": \"{{ env }}-\\1\""
app_upstreams: "{{ ports | dict2items | map('to_json') | map('regex_replace', '\"key\":\\s\"(.*)\"', lookup('vars', 'regex_env')) | map('from_json') }}"
```

but it looks really ugly, is there more good-looking solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    env: staging_
    ports:
      webui: 7200
      webadmin: 7209
      core_api: 7201
      stock_api: 7204
      import_export: 7207
    env_ports_keys: "{{ [env]|product(ports.keys()|list)|map('join') }}"
    env_ports_vals: "{{ ports.values()|list }}"
    env_ports: "{{ dict(env_ports_keys|zip(env_ports_vals)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: env_ports
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  env_ports:
    staging_core_api: 7201
    staging_import_export: 7207
    staging_stock_api: 7204
    staging_webadmin: 7209
    staging_webui: 7200
```

---

To simplify the code, you can create a custom filter

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/dict_utils.py
def prefix_key(d, prefix='prefix'):
    temp = {}
    for key in d.keys():
        temp[prefix + key] = d[key]
    return temp


class FilterModule(object):
    ''' utility filters for operating on dictionary '''
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'prefix_key': prefix_key,
        }
```

The playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    env: staging_
    ports:
      webui: 7200
      webadmin: 7209
      core_api: 7201
      stock_api: 7204
      import_export: 7207
    env_ports: "{{ ports|prefix_key(prefix=env) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: env_ports
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, i know about plugged filters, but it's hard to maintain them on all control hosts, so i'm trying to avoid them

Comment: I've got `Error was a <class 'RuntimeError'>, original message: dictionary changed size during iteration"}`

Comment: I fixed the filter. @Alexey Sviridov: I added an example of how to avoid a custom filter.

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying to solve this issue for myself. I came up with a solution that does not require the use of a filter plugin or a jinja template. Just pure ansible playbook tasks. I did this on the newest version of Ansible, so I can not confirm it will work on older versions.

It works by creating a second dictionary that has the renamed keys and then overwriting the original dictionary with the renamed one. Here is a complete playbook you can run as a proof of concept.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    prefix: staging
    ports:
      webui: 7200
      webadmin: 7209
      core_api: 7201
      stock_api: 7204
      import_export: 7207
    renamed_ports: {}

  tasks:
  - name: set renamed ports
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      renamed_ports: "{{ renamed_ports | combine({ prefix + '-' + item.key: item.value }) }}"
    with_dict: "{{ ports }}"

  - name: rewrite original ports
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      ports: "{{ renamed_ports }}"

  - name: erase renamed ports if you want to
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      renamed_ports:

  - name: print ports
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: ports
...
```

Here is the output of the print ports task:

```
TASK [print ports] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ports": {
        "staging-core_api": 7201,
        "staging-import_export": 7207,
        "staging-stock_api": 7204,
        "staging-webadmin": 7209,
        "staging-webui": 7200
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using jinja2 template module and create a yml file with all the variables.

playbook -->

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ports:
      webui: 7200
      webadmin: 7209
      core_api: 7201
      stock_api: 7204
      import_export: 7207
  tasks:
    - name: debug module
      debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - ports

    - name: template
      template:
        src: templates/template.yml
        dest: templates/dest.yml
```

jinja2 template -->

```
ports:
{% for key, value in ports.iteritems() %}
  staging-{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

output -->

```
ports:
  staging-core_api: 7201
  staging-import_export: 7207
  staging-stock_api: 7204
  staging-webui: 7200
  staging-webadmin: 7209
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but this solution seems even worse for me, due lot of boilerplate code... My solution far from ideal, but at least it fit to two lines. In anyway thank you, i really appreciate it!